# Create Freemarker Configuration bean in Spring, together with parameter

Tags: java, spring, servlets, freemarker

I am having trouble creating a "freemarker.template.Configuration" bean and setting global shared variables in this instance of the Configuration. Something like:

```
<bean id="conf" class="freemarker.template.Configuraton">  
    <property name="sharedVariable" >
        **??**
   </property>
</bean>
```

Is this possible?
I can't use FreeMarkerConfigurer instead of Configurer because I am using servlets (full stack of Spring MVC) as controllers in my project. Is there any way to convert a FreemarkerConfigurer into a Configurer?

Answer (score 0):

The problem stems from that shared variables is not a JavaBean property... but, accidentally, `Configuration` has a `setAllSharedVariables(TemplateHashModelEx)` method,  that's technically a property, so something like this should work (I haven't tried it and my Spring XML is rusty... tell me if there are typos in it):

```
<bean id="conf" class="freemarker.template.Configuraton">
    <property name="allSharedVariables">
        <bean class="freemarker.template.SimpleHash">
            <constructor-arg>
                <map>
                    <entry key='someVarName' value='someValue' />
                    <entry key='otherVarName' value-ref='valueBeanId' />
                </map>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```